# MacOS Finder File Sharing: Connect to a Mac on Network "Using an Apple ID" no longer visible

Tags: macos, finder, network, apple-id, sharing

In the past, I could connect to my other Macs on my home LAN via **Finder > Network > *[Select Mac]* > Connect As… > Using an Apple ID** (assuming I'm signed in to Apple ID on these Macs, and **System Settings > Sharing > File Sharing** is on).

For some reason, the "Using an Apple ID" option is no longer visible. I can only choose "Guest" and "Registered user".

I am currently running MacOS 13 Ventura on my M1 Macs, and Apple's User Guide still mentions that "Using an Apple ID" to connect to a Network computer should be an option: https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/connect-mac-shared-computers-servers-mchlp1140/mac

Does connect "Using an Apple ID" still exist in MacOS Ventura? If yes, what may be the reason for the problem that it is missing? I have signed out of and into Apple ID on one of the Macs, and it didn't help.

Additional information:

- My user under **System Settings > Users & Groups** is an administrator, but I have disabled "Allow user to reset password using Apple ID". Turning that on did not seem to help.
- MacOS Firewall is activated under **System Settings > Network > Firewall**, and *File Sharing (SMB)* is enabled for *Allow incoming connections*. *Automatically allow built-in software to receive incoming connections* is enabled. *Enable stealth mode* is enabled.
- Fortunately, connecting as "Registered User" works in MacOS Ventura 13.3, though it did not work in other recent versions of Ventura ([source](https://www.macrumors.com/2023/03/23/macos-13-3-fixes-network-file-sharing/)).
- Potentially related but probably not: I have this issue with Apple Music Home Sharing over **System Settings > General > Sharing > Media Sharing**: [Apple Music Home Sharing: Skips song and doesn't play audio when Bluetooth speakers/headphones are connected](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/449617/apple-music-home-sharing-skips-song-and-doesnt-play-audio-when-bluetooth-speak)

Comment: I would certainly report the problems to Apple using their feedback page (or using the Feedback Assistant if you're on a beta). AppleID is not an option for me, either; and I have also witnessed similar problems with files and subfolders on several Macs.